# One of containers intermittently can NOT access another container in swarm also

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I'm using docker swarm(17.06 CE) to orchestrate my micro services. The swarm cluster has 3 managers and 1 worker.

I having a Nginx image running in swarm managers globally. I have a Java based micro services having 2 replicas in the same overlay network.

Now I found that one of Nginx containers can NOT access the micro service. The other two Nginx containers can access the service without problem.

```
### there are three nginx containers in swarm  
➜  ~ docker service ps pilipa-prod-nginx 
ID                  NAME                             IMAGE                                             NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE           ERROR               PORTS 
qufld0uu8tk9        pilipa-prod-nginx.4r2p0t892qn55n4uewoymxbp0   registry.i-counting.cn/pilipa/prod/nginx:latest   node02              Running             Running 21 hours ago 
bwjw9c9dm8e1        pilipa-prod-nginx.ixw4urfkdcnkm326vgkw92x8n   registry.i-counting.cn/pilipa/prod/nginx:latest   node01              Running             Running 21 hours ago 
2w2gg83xt6g4        pilipa-prod-nginx.5t63dl8dcj603iyw5l5vv0xvx   registry.i-counting.cn/pilipa/prod/nginx:latest   node03              Running             Running 21 hours ago

### log in the normal Nginx, it can access the micro service without problem  
➜  ~ docker exec --interactive --tty pilipa-prod-nginx.4r2p0t892qn55n4uewoymxbp0.qufld0uu8tk9ieubcimed8fgw 
sh / # ip addr show 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 10901: eth0@if10902: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP
    link/ether 02:42:0a:00:00:2c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.44/24 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.0.0.11/32 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 10903: eth1@if10904: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
    link/ether 02:42:ac:13:00:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.9/16 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
 / # wget 10.0.0.71:8080 Connecting to 10.0.0.71:8080 (10.0.0.71:8080) wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

### log in the problematic Nginx container which can ping the host of micro service, but can NOT access the service
➜  ~ docker exec --interactive --tty pilipa-prod-nginx.ixw4urfkdcnkm326vgkw92x8n.bwjw9c9dm8e1qlx64z5sniw7h sh
/ #
/ #
/ # wget 10.0.0.71:80
Connecting to 10.0.0.71:80 (10.0.0.71:80)
wget: can't connect to remote host (10.0.0.71): Connection refused
/ # ping 10.0.0.71
PING 10.0.0.71 (10.0.0.71): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.71: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.066 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.71: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.076 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.71: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.073 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.71 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.066/0.071/0.076 ms
```

**Upate:**

I tried to use `tcpdump` to capture the traffic in the micro service's host. I could capture the traffics from the normal Nginx container when using `ping 10.0.0.71` and `wget 10.0.0.71:8080` to access the service. However there was no traffic captured either `ping` or `wget` from the problematic Nginx container!

Is it a known bug of swarm's overlay network or something misconfiguration in my env?

Comment: How is he microservice running? As another docker service?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes. The microservice is another service running in same overlay network.

Comment: Is this a problem specific to Host? Take down the swarm and recreate and see if the problem exists on the same host. If so then on the problematic node use `docker swarm leave` and then join it again by generating using the token from another manager

Comment: @TarunLalwani I'm not sure. The problem is gone after stopping the problematic container and swarm recreated it.